# Meaning of scanner isn't synchronized

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader

I was going through the differences between scanner and BufferedReader in Java and one point which I could not understand was that said

**Scanner is not synchronized while BufferedReader is.**

Now can anyone please explain what it means?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231369/scanner-vs-bufferedreader
question has already asked before

Comment: [Here's an explanation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html) of synchronization in Java. But where exactly did you see that quote?

Comment: I am not asking the difference between scanner and BufferedReader.I am asking what is the meaning of synchronization of BufferedReader and not of scanner.Is it clear now?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is the scanner in java is not thread safe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31024254/is-the-scanner-in-java-is-not-thread-safe)

Comment: @Priyamal That question doesn't address the question of the author. The author wants to know what `synchronized` means, and that question doesn't ever explain what `synchronized` is, it only refers to the word multiple times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Literally, it means what it says.  Key operations of the `BufferedReader` API are implemented using `synchronized` blocks, and the equivalent operations in `Scanner` are not.

This means that a `BufferedReader` can be "safely" shared between multiple threads<sup>1</sup>, whereas a `Scanner` cannot.  A `Scanner` is inherently non-thread-safe, even if it wraps a thread-safe input source.

---

<sup>1 - Actually, this does not absolve you from thinking about threading.  If you have multiple threads calling `read(...)` operations on the same `BufferedReader` without some form of coordination, then there is no way to know which thread will read which characters from the stream.  By some definitions, that would make the usage non-thread-safe.  The disposition of the characters to the right threads is usually important to the correctness of the application.</sup>

Comment: For a certain, not necessarily intuitive, definition of "safely".  And of course `Scanner`s can be safely shared between multiple threads, too, for a different definition of "safely" that involves external synchronization.