# How can I clear the input buffer to ignore input given before prompt?

Tags: java, io, buffer, java.util.scanner

I have a client/server game where users take turns giving input to the game. I want anything a user types when it is not their turn to be ignored. I want to scan only the inputs the user gives after they are prompted. I am using java.util.Scanner for input, but I can't find a way to "flush" the scanner buffer without the program hanging. I also cannot find examples of other input reading methods doing what I want.

This is what I tried:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    //do game stuff
    //I don't care about anything typed at this time
while(in.hasNextLine()){
    in.nextLine();
}

System.out.println("Enter your move:");
String input = in.nextLine();
```

Comment: There isn't a way to do what you want without using unbuffered terminal io (using native libraries).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Hmm I assumed there was a way to do it because it's a specific requirement for a homework assignment. Thanks though

Comment: is this a multi-threaded app? how will you know when it is your turn?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to disable a `Scanner` and re-enable it. Here are a few suggestions:

You can manually empty the `Scanner` before the player's turn like so (what (I think) you've been doing):

```
while(in.hasNext()) in.next();
```

Or, you can close the scanner at the end of the player's turn and instantiate a new one at the beginning of the next turn (you can't reopen a closed `Scanner`):

```
//Player's turn
//
//End of player's turn...
in.close();

//Beginning of player's turn
in = new Scanner(System.in);
```

This, however, will throw an `IllegalStateException` if you try to access the `Scanner` after it has been closed. To solve this, try (on Java 7 and later) the try-with-resources block:

```
//Overridden close method because you don't want to close System.in
try (Scanner in = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(System.in)
    {public void close() throws IOException {}})) {
    System.out.println("Enter your move:");
    String input = in.nextLine();
}
//End of player's turn
//Scanner is automatically closed and this code is out of the scanner's scope
```

I think this last option is your best bet. It restricts the scope of the `Scanner` to the relevant code, and it automates the instantiating/closing. Plus, it uses a (relatively) recent Java feature, so that might be the required answer to your problem.

Comment: Your first suggestion is what I initially tried and it caused my program to hang. The try block as you showed it gives "java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found" when calling in.nextLine() after the first time i use the scanner.

Comment: It works fine with me, using only this basic code. If you're getting that exception, wrap the offending lines in a `while(in.hasNextLine())` block. Are you running the code on different threads? Since `nextLine()` is a blocking call, it's surprising that other code could be read before a next line is entered.

Comment: My bad, System.in doesn't play well with try-with-resources. Give me a moment to update my answer.

Comment: yes this is multithreaded which i think is what's causing me so much difficulty. Playing around it seems like your solution works in a single threaded environment but I can't get it to work for me

Comment: @3802400 Well that's a whole other issue, and your question doesn't mention anything about multiple threads. `Scanner` isn't thread-safe. See [Is the scanner in java not thread safe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31024254/is-the-scanner-in-java-not-thread-safe).