# Java BufferedReader read line by customized delimiter

Tags: java, bufferedreader

`BufferedReader`'s `readline()` reads a line defined by '\n', is it possible to read a line defined by other delimiter, e.g. `^B`?
Thanks

Comment: Not just `\n`: "A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed."

Comment: No, you can't do that directly with `BufferedReader` but you _can_ just read in bytes and scan yourself for a custom delimeter.

Comment: So how about writing a class similar to BufferedReader, and overwrite the readline() method?

Answer (score 5):

You can't do it with `BufferedReader`, however, you can use `Scanner` and call `useDelimiter()` method, e.g.:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("<file>"));
scanner.useDelimiter("\b");
```

[Here's](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter%28java.util.regex.Pattern%29) the javadoc.

Comment: what if it's a big file? will it create memory issue?

Comment: It should be fine if you are processing one line at a time and not storing everything into memory.

Comment: Be aware that Scanner is not thread-safe (key methods are not synchronized like key methods of BufferedReader are). The asker may know that (if that is the reason for the question, as opposed to not knowing Scanner exists and as opposed to only being concerned about memory use), but a later reader with the same question may not know that and may be lead astray by the suggestion to use Scanner that does not mention the multithreading issue. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31024254/is-the-scanner-in-java-not-thread-safe