# Java scanner read only the first line of a file

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, filereader

I wrote this code cause I need to read some line of a file to get the data and put them in a object.
The trouble is that the scanner read only the first line .
I try to do the print `System.out.println(sc.hasNext());` with this and debug the code but when the first cycle is do the while condition (sc.hasNext()) return false .
but in the file there is 2 line.

```
Scanner sc =null;
    int[] counter=new int[users.length];


    for(int i=0;i<users.length-1;i++){
        sc= new Scanner(new FileReader("src/MailListUser"+String.valueOf(i+1)+".txt")).useDelimiter("\\s*^^\\s*");
        while(sc.hasNext()){
            String mail =sc.next();
            String [] data= mail.split(":::");
            Email email;
            String dat=data[5].replaceAll("_", " ");
            DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy",Locale.ENGLISH);
            Date date = format.parse(dat);
            email = new Email(data[1],data[2],data[3],data[4],date,Integer.parseInt(data[6]));
            if(i+1==1) {
                counter[i]++;
                mbUser1.add(email);
            }
            else if(i+1==2){
                counter[i]++;
                mbUser2.add(email);
            }
            else if(i+1==3){
                counter[i]++;
                mbUser3.add(email);
            }

        }

    }
    sc.close();
```

there is the code .
the file contain :

```
^^:::user1@unito.it:::user1@unito.it:::grbvfcsx:::yrdfsx:::Wed_Sep_05_09:25:51_CEST_2018:::-1568000361:::^^
  ^^:::user1@unito.it:::user1@unito.it:::rgvfcdsx:::trvedcs:::Wed_Sep_05_09:27:53_CEST_2018:::482784668:::^^
```

every line of this file start with ^^ and end with ^^

I can't understand why this code read only one line

Comment: why are you using a Scanner? Try https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html

Comment: Before this line: `String dat=data[5].replaceAll("_", " ");` you should check that data is not null and has at least 6 items. You should also escape the `^^` because `^` matches the beginning of a line

Comment: @ScaryWombat I try to do with the bufferedReader but work only if the string in data[4] have only one line , but this string is needed to have one or more line ,example "hello \n how are you ? \n bye" .... in fact I use scanner cause it offer the method useDelimiter to delimit every line of the file that I try to read, is anything similar to useDelimiter in bufferedReader ?

Comment: @StephaneM it is impossible to is null cause when I write it I another class I assured myself that it is never empty .furthermore  data have certainly at least 6 items because the split method split he string every times it find ":::" and when I write the line I assured to write the separator ":::"

Comment: @ScaryWombat in fact here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43819083/7720930)   is written that in bufferedReader haven't delimiters to use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In regular expressions, `^` is a special character. It represents start of input, rather than just the character `^` itself.

You need to escape it in your pattern:

```
"\\s*\\^\\^\\s*"
```

Comment: I put this string "\\s*\\^\\^\\s*" as parameter in useDelimiter method but the result is the same .     a string with multiple line like this as follow example the scanner can read because between 4th and 5th ::: are more than 1 line `^^:::user3@unito.it:::user1@unito.it:::object:::multiple 
                                                                                                                             line 
                                    text:::Wed_Sep_05_14:11:44_CEST_2018:::466540663:::^^
`

Comment: @duca you said "the result is the same". I'm afraid I have to not believe you on that, and demand that you re-examine your results, and instead of saying "the result is the same" to describe what are actually the new results you're observing.

Comment: sorry ,**you have right** , it is a my error cause use delimiter it only to end a string for example mystring^^ and not for string that start and end with the same pattern like ^^mystring^^, thanks for your help